# Querying a lookup relationship

Tags: soql

I have two Objects object1 & object2.

In object1 there is a field, `field1` with Lookup to object2. Now what I need to do is query object2 fields based on the id of `field1` How can I perform this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

Let say you know the Id of Object1. So you can read the Field1__c from that Object1 - this will be Id of the Object2.

```
Id idOfObject2 = [ Select Field1__r.Id From Object1 Where Id = :someVar ].Field1__r.Id;
```

Now we reading Object2 fields:

```
Object2 obj2 = [ Select Field1__c, Field2__c From Object2 Where Id = :idOfObject2 ];
```

Or we can do the same simpler:

```
Object2 obj2 = [ Select Field1__c, Field2__c From Object2 
                 Where Id IN (Select Field1__c From Object1 Where Id = :someVar) ];
```

---

I think you can do it like this:

```
Select Id, Name From Object2 Where Id = :Object1.field1__c
```

You can read more about lookup relationships at the official doc site: [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)

Comment: I can't go with the second one because all my fields are in object2,so need to query object2....and for the first one getting error as  `Compile Error: Variable does not exist: object1__r.field1__c`

Comment: What is your key? I mean - based on which id you are reading the data?

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this thriugh one single query -

```
[Select  Field2__r.Field2_field__c FROM Object1 obj where obj.id = :Object1ID];
```